# Dot Net Nuke : Selecting different skin files based on the browser width change

Tags: c#, asp.net, dotnetnuke

Is there any way of selecting different skin files(.ascx files) in DNN when there is a change in the browser or window width?

In addition to it, is there any event in asp.net that is triggered whenever there is any change in the width/size of the browser?

Answer (score 1):

You can create separate sites for different devices using DNN's "Device Preview Management"and "Site Redirection"

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/community/learn/video-library/view-video/video/532/view/details/redirecting-website-visitors-to-your-mobile-website-using-dotnetnuke

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question, you'll need to use JavaScript to update the stylesheet url based on browser width. In javascript, you can get the viewport's width with

```
window.innerWidth
```

However, a much better approach would be to employ [responsive design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) in the design of your theme. Modern CSS is capable of handling much of the calculation for modifying layout based on viewport size with an elegant and simple syntax.

To assist you in this, you may want to use a responsive design framework such as [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/)